# "Independent" vs "irrespective"?

Tags: difference

> Irrespective of A, B is always true.
>
> Independent of A, B is always true.

Are these words complete synonyms in this context? Or is there any reason to use one over the other?

Answer (score 3):

I am not a logician but as I understand it:

1. B is always true (regardless) irrespective of A.
   States that A in no way impacts on the truth of B.
2. B is always true independent of A.
   Implies that B might not be true when not independent of A.

That's to say that when A impacts on B, B might not be true.

Comment: Wouldn't 2. need to be "B is always true WHEN independent of A" to have the meaning you say it has? Also, in your versions shouldn't there be commas after "true"?

Comment: @MaxD **When** would make clear what is implied.  Not sure about commas!